# Is it possible to connect Azure to google drive?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, google-drive-api

I am writing a system in ASP.NET CORE and uploading it to AZURE.

I'm looking for a free place to store files that customers upload.

Azure storage costs money so I thought of connecting it to Google drive
Is it possible? And can you explain to me how?

Comment: You seem to have found the Google Drive API tag. Have you found their documentation? Tried to implement it? What's stopping you from doing so? From Google's perspective, they don't care if your app is hosted in Azure or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You could defiantly store your files in Google drive.  Use the google drive api, do it with a service account as it sounds like you will only be uploading to an account you control.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Drive Service account Authentication Sample",
                    });
```

[Uploading files to Google Drive API with a service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5b0ivBYqeQ)

as for the hosting in azure part.  I recommend using the json key file as opposed to the p12 certificate file.  I have had issues with that in azure before.

## Upload from memory

As the files your users are uploading may just be a memory stream rather then files stored on your hard drive this is also possible using a MemoryStream

```
var uploadString = "Test";
var fileName = "ploadFileString.txt";
// Upload file Metadata
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
     Name = fileName,
     Parents = new List<string>() { "1R_QjyKyvET838G6loFSRu27C-3ASMJJa" }  // folder to upload the file to
     };

var fsSource = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uploadString ?? ""));

string uploadedFileId;
            
// Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
request.Fields = "*";
var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
   {
   Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
   }
// the file id of the new file we created
uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
```

[How to upload to Google Drive API from memory with C#](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-upload-to-google-drive-api-from-memory-with-c/)

Comment: Would -1 care to comment?  This solution will work just fine in asp .net core.

Comment: thanks, i will try this!! and the -1 is not for me

Comment: I hope it helps let me know if you have any issues.  The tutorial and video should help as well.